# Jquery script stops working after ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form with 2 select inputs. The 2nd select options are filtered after the first select.   However my jquery event listener for the first select stops working after the ajax response returning the list of options for the second event.
Testing in dev tools shows that the an ajax request is no longer is sent after the first. However reentering the script below in the console again starts it working again. I'm not sure why it stops working after an ajax request.

My script is:

```
$('#id_elec_supplier').change(function () {
      console.log($(this).val())
      var supplier = $(this).val()

      $.ajax({
        url: '/users/current_supply/',
        data: {
          'supplier': supplier
        },

        success: function (data) {
          $('form').replaceWith(data)
        }
      })})
```

Comment: Are you replacing id_elec_supplier element?? Can u post html and data returned from ajax?

Comment: you need to iterate over `data` and create `option` html with them and then replace second select-box html with your created html from this `data`

Comment: what is being returned from the server? a string?

Comment: yes a string from a template, ( full template here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754862/form-with-dynamic-select-inputs-ajax-stops-working)